# What does a leaning cross on a gravestone mean?

Tags: religion, united-kingdom, death

I found this photo I took in 2010 of a [gravestone located in Fenstanton Parish Church graveyard](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Fenstanton+Parish+Church/@52.3010728,-0.0653503,20z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d8742ac457f475:0xec6a0d4af3391277!8m2!3d52.3009474!4d-0.0653762). It is dated 1886.

[image]

I've done a little research ([1](http://www.graveaddiction.com/symbol.html),[2](https://www.thoughtco.com/photo-gallery-of-cemetery-symbolism-4123061),[3](https://www.ghostvillage.com/ghostcommunity/index.php?showtopic=32291)) but none of them were especially helpful.

Why does the cross on this gravestone lean?

Comment: I asked that same question as a kid and was told that was supposed to symbolize the cross that Jesus carried on his back. Of course that is just what I was told so take it at that.

Comment: Need it mean anything more than that the stoncarver perhaps couldn't fit an upright one in with all the lettering?

Comment: This link provides some theories, but I've found nothing more definite. https://www.gotquestions.org/sideways-cross.html

Comment: It appears not to be a leaning cross, but one resting on two points. It could just be a stylization, or maybe the person is "resting".

Comment: You may wish to ask this question at Christianity.SE.  There are some very knowledgeable people in that SE who may have insights on this tradition,  which may be Anglican Christian in origin.

Comment: My parents solemnly told me when I was about ten that it means they were unjustly killed, usually by hanging. I've never heard this from anyone else though and admittedly, my parents were a bit crazy.

Answer (score 15):

It is a [Portate Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_cross_variants), also called cross of [St. Gilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_of_Sempringham). There were some pages which stated that "portate" derives from Latin "portare" (carry), and that it symbolizes the cross Christ carried, but I found no reliable source to support it.

Answer (score 2):

It means several things the most common is that Jesus has finished his journey carrying the cross and has laid it down

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Sources to support your assertion would greatly improve this answer.